# VirtualBox network performance on Mac OS X host

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I'm getting terrible network performance running VirtualBox 4.3.20 on Mac OS X 10.10.1 host. The guests I've tried were Ubuntu 14.04 and Debian 7 using bridged and NAT networking. A simple HTTP request from host to guest take more than 20 seconds to complete. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a host-only network and use port forwarding on your host into the VM if you need access to the VM from somewhere else in the network. Mounting the VM to your network using the Bridged connection is always on the slow side.